# ORACLE PL/SQL: The lost last chunk

Tags: oracle, plsql

Please help me to solve this ORACLE PL/SQL problem.

I have the following code:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE
      P_COMMIT_STEP   NUMBER := 10000;       -- Commit every 10000 record copied
      V_QUERY         VARCHAR2 (4000) := NULL;
      MY_CURSOR       SYS_REFCURSOR;

      TYPE FETCH_ARRAY IS TABLE OF MY_TABLE_BACKUP%ROWTYPE;

      S_ARRAY         FETCH_ARRAY;
   BEGIN
      V_QUERY := 'SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE_BACKUP';

      OPEN MY_CURSOR FOR V_QUERY;

      LOOP
         FETCH MY_CURSOR
         BULK COLLECT INTO   S_ARRAY
         LIMIT P_COMMIT_STEP;

         FORALL I IN 1 .. S_ARRAY.COUNT
            INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_BIS                               /*+ APPEND */
              VALUES   S_ARRAY (I);

         COMMIT;


         EXIT WHEN MY_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE MY_CURSOR;

      COMMIT;
   END;
END;
```

Since the commit step is 10000, the copy works for a multiple of 10000 record.
So, if the original table has 1000010 records, only 1000000 records will be copied.
Where is the error?
The code seems correct, in my opinion.
Thank you very much for considering my request.

Comment: Try to debug it. Use dbms_output.put_line(S_array.count) to check the count at the end.

Comment: it will commit at after the final row even this is within a 10000 boundary, commits will also run once the procedure finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [in this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html), you shouldn't rely on `%NOTFOUND` with `bulk collect` and `forall`. Check how many rows were fetched:

```
  LOOP
     FETCH MY_CURSOR
     BULK COLLECT INTO   S_ARRAY
     LIMIT P_COMMIT_STEP;

     FORALL I IN 1 .. S_ARRAY.COUNT
        INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_BIS                               /*+ APPEND */
          VALUES   S_ARRAY (I);

     COMMIT;


     EXIT WHEN S_ARRAY.COUNT < P_COMMIT_STEP;
  END LOOP;
```

Your first thousand iterations will get 10000 rows, so the count will equal your limit for all of those, and it will continue. The next one will get only 10 rows, so it will exit after the `forall`.

It *should* still work with the `%NOTFOUND` check at the end of the loop - the article is really talking about it being an issue if you use it to exit before processing the partial batch - and [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#BABJIAFH) shows that pattern; but in some circumstances it seems not to. Having said that, I can't reproduce the issue from your code in 11.2.0.3.

Incidentally, committing inside a loop is generally a bad idea unless you've made the block restartable.

Comment: I use the same general structure for ETL scenarios with millions or even billions of rows to process. But I do have to use a `commit` in the loop due to the amount of data, so I use a `mod` operation on a row counter to only `commit` every x loop iterations.

Comment: Thank you very much, Alex Poole, for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

HI small modification to your Forall loop

```
FORALL I IN S_ARRAY.first .. S_ARRAY.last
            INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_BIS                               /*+ APPEND */
              VALUES   S_ARRAY (I);
```

I think it will work for you.

Comment: That will error if it fetches zero rows (which it may do if the table is empty, or has an exact multiple of the limit). `1..count` is safer. (Or you could do a separate empty check [as shown here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#BABCCJCB).

Comment: Hi @alex poole May I know what are the values of v.first and v.last if a table doesn't contains any data.

Comment: HI @alex it is working if the limit value is exact multiple of total rows of that table and it is also working if that cursor is  fetching zero rows also. if you need more explanation i will post sample code.

Comment: Sorry, I am confusing two things; first and last are null, and it doesn't error (but also doesn't help solve the problem); you get an error from a `for` loop, not a `foralll` loop. My mistake.